# Javascript: Append to a value of a key, where the value is a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I will make reference to the following: 
test object
species object.

Inside of the "species" object, I have two properties: "species" and "state".
The "state" property has a value which is an array with states.
I want to create a key for the "test" object which corresponds to each state inside of the "state" array located in the object species object.

Example output (look at the code below to see where these values come from):

```
{a: ["tiger", "dog"], b: ["tiger"], c: ["dog","lion"], d: ["tiger", "dog"], e: ["lion:]}
```

The idea is that I want to list the species within each state, and species are often not restricted to a single state, so one species in Kentucky might also be found in Ohio. I want that species to be listed as an inhabitant of both states in the manner described above.

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: test[d].append is not a function
    at script.js:272
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runVis (script.js:270)
    at script.js:178
```

And here is my code:

```
  var test = new Object();
  var species = [{species: "tiger", state: ["a","b","d"]},
                 {species: "dog", state: ["a","c","d"]},
                 {species: "lion", state: ["c", "e"]}
               ];
  for (i in species) {
    species[i].state.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d in test) {
        test[d].append(species[i].species)
      }
      else {
        test[d] = [species[i].species];
        console.log(test);
      }
    })
  }
```

I create a key for the state if it does not yet exist. I also store the value for the species of that state in an array for the first time. When I run across a species which lives in a state that already has a key, I want to append that species to the array which is the value of the state key.

Comment: it's called an `Array`, and array's have methods like `.push` to add to them

Comment: Thank you so much! It is now fixed. I appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `push` not `append`:

```
for (i in species) {
  species[i].state.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d in test) {
      test[d].push(species[i].species)
    } else {
      test[d] = [species[i].species];
      console.log(test);
    }
  })
}
```

You can also use `reduce` instead like so:

```js
var species = [{species: "tiger", state: ["a","b","d"]},{species: "dog", state: ["a","c","d"]},{species: "lion", state: ["c", "e"]}];
var test = species.reduce((acc, { species, state }) => {
  state.forEach(s => {
    acc[s] = acc[s] || [];
    acc[s].push(species);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: No worries @MichaelRamage - I've updated my answer as well with a different solution.